# Need to write a function that joins two values from two separate columns together of different lengths

Tags: python, concatenation, pickle, nan

I have a `.pkl` file that has looks something like this but has at least 300 rows:

| X | Y | Z | M |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -0.522 | 3 | 0.55 | Yes |
| 0.44 | 5 | NaN | No |
| NaN | NaN | 0.241 | Maybe |
| 0.325 | 3 | Nan | Yes |

I want to get a list of values for Y and M [3 = Yes, 5 = No, 3 = Yes ] but in some of the rows there are NaNs.

Currently I am able to get Y without the NaNs
But there are no NaNs in M. I need to remove the M values that do not have a Y value. (Y = NaN)

Then `print(Y_no_nans together with M_no_Y_nans)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following (df is your dataframe):

```
df2 = df[(pd.notna(df['Y']) & (pd.notna(df['M']))]
result = list(zip(df2['Y'], df2['M']))

print(result)
```

Output

```
[(3, 'Yes'), (5, 'No'), (3, 'Yes')]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken about what you want, you can simply use `print(df[["Y","M"]].dropna())`.
If you wish to remove the `NaN` from the data altogether, pass an `inplace=True` argument in the `dropna` method (`df.dropna(inplace=True)`).